# False warning for placement new?

Tags: c++, alignment, placement-new

I have the following code:

```
#include "type_traits"
#include <new>


void foo()
{
    std::aligned_storage<10,alignof(long)> storage;
    new (&storage) int(12);
}
```

I have some storage defined (with length 10 bytes), and I am placement `new`ing an `int` into that location

gcc 7.3 gives the following warning:

```
<source>:10:10: warning: placement new constructing an object of type 'int' and size '4' in a region of type 'std::aligned_storage<10, 8>' and size '1' [-Wplacement-new=]
     new (&storage) int(12);
```

If I am not incorrect this warning is incorrect.  Am I missing something here or is this warning spurious?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`std::aligned_storage` is a trait with a nested `type` member. That `type` is of the correct size and alignment. The trait itself may have no data members, and therefore will get the default object size, which is 1.

So the fix is simple:

```
std::aligned_storage<10,alignof(long)>::type storage;
```

Comment: You could also write `std::aligned_storage_t`. I've sometimes made this error (with other types) by simply forgetting the `_t`. It can be quite difficult to spot